# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this question is quite redundant already but in my case I can't figure out what went wrong with my code or probably with the data inside my table.

I'm using MS SQL 2005 in running this:

```
Select * 
from table
where [Scheduled Date] between '2013-07-01' and getdate()
Order by [Scheduled Date] asc
```

Two things that I did that turns out fine when I run it:

1. I changed `getdate()` into something like `'2013-09-01'` but I don't think that the problem is in the function `getdate()`.

I always get:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

2. I tried to select each column. First to select `col_1` (success), added `col_2` (success), added up to `col_9` (success), but when I tried to add `col_10` it failed. I have a total of 13 columns.

**sp_help**

[image]

Comment: getdate() returns you date and time,so better `cast(getdate() as date)` and why the tag `mysql`

Comment: That works fine for me. Your problem is not with that query.

Comment: the problem is with your main query, can you please post it? What is happening is that your subquery returns multiple results, and you are most likely comparing the results of this to some arbitrary value, which works if your return result only has 1 record, as soon as there are more than 1 it fails.

Comment: @DD [check this post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Hi @JanR. I don't have the main query. Would it be possible that the table contains a duplicate data since I don't see any ID in the column of this table.

Comment: Duplicate data shouldn't be the problem, it appears that the "BETWEEN" and "AND" is the problem. Can you try using: [Scheduled Date] >= '2013-07-01' AND  [Scheduled Date] <= GetDate()

Comment: I'm still having the same result. I tried to select each column. first to select col_1 (success), added col_2 (success), added up to col_9 (success), but when I tried to add col_10 it failed. I have a total of 13 columns. Do you have any idea about that? @JanR

Comment: can you run sp_help <tableName> on your table? and post the results?

Comment: Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f3pnl3wh1u8ohu/testing.png @JanR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a view in your query.

[image]

> but when I tried to add col_10 it failed.

`col_10` in your view is a subquery that returns more than one row.

Comment: Hi Mikael. So what should I do about this?

Comment: @DetectiveDrone you need to fix the view or you should stop using it. Perhaps use the base tables directly.

Answer (score -1):

That's because anything in a where clause must be a logic expression. Getdate() is not a logic expression. Try this...

```
Select * from table
where [Scheduled Date] >= '2013-07-01' and [Scheduled Date] <= getdate()
Order by [Scheduled Date] asc
```